# convert date to string in COM c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I spend whole night to find out single example to convert DATE datatype of c++ to string in COMM.
My interface function returns following values and i want show that values in human redable format.
Like,

```
DATE JobStartTime;
CurrentJob->get_StartTime(&JobStartTime);
```

And it return valules like,
16324.5455 etc.

When i go to defination of DATE it show me something like,

```
typedef double DATE;
```

Which is again confuse me.As a DATE it is again double,so how would i convert it into something like,

**02/05/2013 11.41.25**

etc.
Please help me i am very new in comm.

Comment: Can u show DATE, and get_Starttime? And current job structure/class or something

Comment: DATE is predefine data datatype of c++.and Get_starttime() just return it.and i am using comm of third party do i dobt have body of Get_Starttime().But i can show you values.

Comment: Ok, I forgot. And the rest?

Comment: Its return always floating values like,45688.2546,788445.

Comment: Ok, but does this values mean something? If it does you can write convert function

Comment: @Antua Well I think the problem is that CoderBlock doesn't know what the values mean. But it's all documented under MSDN and a quick google tells you all you need to know.

Comment: yup it has some meaning but if you use DATE datatype in any function it will return you same values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DATE is the COM Automation type. You can use [VariantTimeToSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221440%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  or [VariantTimeToDosDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

```
DATE JobStartTime;
CurrentJob->get_StartTime(&JobStartTime);
SYSTEMTIME st;
VariantTimeToSystemTime(JobStartTime, &st);
```

You can then also turn it into a FILETIME using [SystemTimeToFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
FILETIME ft;
SystemTimeToFileTime(st, &ft);
```

Comment: Exactly,Do you have any example on this fucntions.Bcause parameter really confuse me.Please.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your own conversion function to get this as you want. @John's link is perfect for you [msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/82ab7w69%28v=vs.80%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/82ab7w69%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Shortcut:
`0.00` should mean `30 December 1899, midnight`
Every `+1.0` is one `+day` and
every `+0.25` is `+6 hours`.

For example:
`2.0` is `1 January 1900, midnight` 
`2.25` is `1 January 1900, 6 AM` 
`2.5` is `1 January 1900, noon`

Answer (score 0):

Look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/by5d3kb1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

I've never worked with this class but from the documentation it looks like this is what you want

```
DATE JobStartTime;
...
CString formattedDate = COleDateTime(JobStartTime).Format();
```

Here's how to do what you want with `VariantTimeToSystemTime`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    DATE date = 16324.5455;
    SYSTEMTIME systime;
    VariantTimeToSystemTime(date, &systime);
    printf("%02u/%02u/%04u %02d.%02d.%02d\n", systime.wDay, systime.wMonth, systime.wYear, systime.wHour, systime.wMinute, systime.wSecond);
}
```

output is 09/09/1944 13.05.31

Comment: Nop its totally MFC approch i am using normal c++.I dont dont have class CString or COleDateTime.

Comment: OK then the DATE type is explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/82ab7w69%28v=vs.80%29.aspx and you'll have to write your own conversion function as Antua suggests.

Comment: I already go throught this but there should be function to convert.And even if i tried to write my own conversion its not possible because i dont have meaning of floating vlaues of DATE given by microsoft.:(

Comment: @CoderBlock On that page I linked to it says 'Days are represented by whole number increments starting with 30 December 1899, midnight as time zero. Hour values are expressed as the absolute value of the fractional part of the number.' What more do you need to know?

Comment: could please help me on function VariantTimeToDosDateTime given by @simon

Answer (score 0):

I think best option is VariantTimeToSystemTime (as Simon states) and then GetTimeFormat (locale dependent)